# I need a regular expression that can match ending tags

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I need a regular expression that can match ending tags such as `</something>` and any and ALL data after it. Please help!

Example:

```
$html = '
   <div id="footer">
       <div class="wrap">
           <strong class="logo"><a href="#">College</a></strong>
           <ul><li><a href="#">Emergencies</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Copyright</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Member of The Colleges</a></li>
           </ul><p>© 2010 College</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</body></html>
li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Copyright</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Member of The Colleges</a></li>
           </ul><p>© 2010 College</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</body></html>';

$html = preg_replace("#</html>.*#i", '', $html);
print ($html);
```

Comment: same question as the ending </html> tag regex question earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags can be hidden inside comments, cdata, script and other places, and/or it could just be invalid. If you say its not markup of any kind, you could do something like this:

`/<\/something\s*>((?:(?!<\/something\s*>)[\S\s])+)/` then peel off capture group 1 in a global loop. Don't need to capture the tag unless its a (?:something|something_else|...)

**EDIT**
Your example doesen't work because you are not using the /s modifier. It works in Perl as `$html =~ s/<\/html>.*//s;`. This `$html =~ s/<\/html>[\S\s]*//;` works without the /s modifier.

Change yours to `#</html>[\S\s]*#i` or use the /s modifier. Dot `.` will match any character except newline. With /s modifier it will match newline too.

**and more** Just tried it, use `$html = preg_replace("#</html>.*#is", '', $html);`

Comment: Try using my example that I will paste up top. Test it at writecodeonline.com/php

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to parse HTML with regular expressions.  Regular expressions are inadequate for parsing HTML safely.  What you need is an HTML parser.  Take a look at PHP's [DOM module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: +1 ... and the obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Please don't use that link.  It is useless for beginners.  It is clever only for those who understand, and confusing at best for those who don't.

Comment: @Sean Vieira--good link.

Answer (score 0):

```
@"</[\da-zA-Z]+>.*"
```

or for a specific tag

```
@"</myTag>.*"
```

Making sure to set the regex options to ignore case. Although make sure something that parses xml isn't more helpful.

Comment: Apologies, I was mistaken. I forgot the wrapping #

Comment: What's weird is that when I update to use your second example, it works but only matches so far... array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "" } is the output of var_dump($matches);

Comment: Try using my example that I will paste up top. Test it at http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will change your mind but probably regex's aren't the best way to pull ending tags out of html anyway. Jeff Atwood did a great essay about why this is not the best approach for solving this particular issue.

[Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)